# App crashing with several bitmaps on SurfaceView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, surfaceview

I have tried to create a simple screen with 2 bitmaps on SurfaceView

The application builds fine but then proceeds to crash at runtime and I can't seem to figure it out.
I successfully made one appear on the screen but failed to add another one successfully.

### Error Log

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
```

### Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

surfaceView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(view);

    view = new surfaceView(this);
}

public class surfaceView extends SurfaceView {

    public surfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        new Anim().start();
    }

    public class Anim extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int purpleBird = R.drawable.red1;
            int redBird = R.drawable.bird1;


            draw(purpleBird, redBird);
        }

        private void draw(int purpleBird, int redBird) {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            Bitmap purpleBirdBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), purpleBird);
            Bitmap redBirdBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), redBird);

            canvas.drawBitmap(purpleBirdBit, 100, 100, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(redBirdBit, 400, 400, paint);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the Logs. Then it would be easier to find what is happening.

Comment: Updated the question with error log